# An identity of time-ordered operators that intertwines between the Schrödinger picture and the interaction picture

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, time-evolution

Let $V(t)$ and $H_0$ be two operators where $V(t)$ has explicit time dependence while $H_0$ is time independent.

I am trying to prove the interesting identity,

$$T(e^{-i\int_{t_{0}}^{t} dt' (H_0+V(t'))})~=~e^{-i(t-t_{0})H_0}\times T(e^{-i\int_{t_{0}}^{t} dt' e^{i(t'-t_{0})H_0}V(t')e^{-i(t'-t_0)H_0}}).$$

If $V(t)$ and $H_0$ commutes at all times, life would have been much more easier and plain. I have tried the brute force and have failed, miserably.

Could anyone provide a small hint to nudge me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP's identity follows from the operator identity
$$ \forall t\geq 0:~~ L_1(t)~=~L_2(t), \tag{0}$$
where we have introduced (for later convenience) the following shorthand notation
$$L_1(t)~:=~T\left[\exp\left\{\int_0^t \! ds ~(H_0+V(s))\right\}\right]\tag{1}$$ 
and
$$L_2(t)~:=~e^{tH_0} T\left[\exp\left\{\int_0^t \! ds ~e^{-sH_0}V(s)e^{sH_0}\right\}\right].\tag{2}$$

*Sketched proof of the operator identity (0):* Show that both the two operators $L_i(t)$, $i\in\{1,2\}$, satisfy the following first-order initial value problem (IVP)
$$ \frac{d L_i(t)}{dt}~=~ (H_0+V(t))L_i(t), \qquad L_i(t\!=\!0)={\bf 1}.\tag{3} $$ 
By the [uniqueness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation#Existence_and_uniqueness_of_solutions) of the solution to the IVP (3), the operator identity (0) follows.

Comment: Does a simple proof of the uniqueness exist?